Lazily loading large strings from a JSON file in Rust
I have a large JSON file containing a medium number of very large strings and I don't want to store it all in memory at once.
Is it possible to use serde-json (or similar) to load it, except for these large strings. For the large strings I want it to load them lazily. For example it could store the file offset and length instead of the actual string, and then provide a function to actually read the string.

this require specialized json parser, AFAIK json is not mean to be use for big data and so no one should need such feature.

You're living in a dream world if you think nobody uses JSON for huge amounts of data just because they shouldn't.

Not sure why the downvotes, this is a perfectly reasonable question. I would try finding Rust bindings to simdjson

Yeah who knows; classic SO. Anyway I had a look into serde_json and unfortunately although it does have the file offset info sort of available in serde_json::de::Deserializer::read, it's private. I guess I could fork serde_json but I'd rather not.

@Timmmm I wanted to say that I don't think there is a lib for that yet but that an interesting idea. Still json should not be for that :p

You will need a custom parse for storing the parsing data lazily, but
use serde_json::from_reader(_) help a bit, along with std::io::BufReader

Edit
change print_mem_stat() to Peak allocation.

Rough Experiment
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter, Read};

use peak_alloc::PeakAlloc;

#[global_allocator]
static PEAK_ALLOC: PeakAlloc = PeakAlloc;

fn print_mem_stat() {
    let current_mem = PEAK_ALLOC.current_usage_as_mb();
    println!("This program currently uses {} MB of RAM.", current_mem);
    let peak_mem = PEAK_ALLOC.peak_usage_as_gb();
    println!("The max amount that was used {}", peak_mem);
    println!();
}

fn main() {
    println!("start");
    print_mem_stat();
    let path = std::env::current_dir().unwrap().join("data.json");
    
    {
        let data = (0..(1<<26)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let f = std::fs::OpenOptions::new().write(true).truncate(true).create(true).open(&path).unwrap();
        let wtr = BufWriter::new(f);
        serde_json::to_writer_pretty(wtr, &data).unwrap();
        println!("writing data");
        print_mem_stat();
    }
    
    // parse form a BufReader;
    {
        let f = std::fs::OpenOptions::new().read(true).open(&path).unwrap();
        let rdr = BufReader::new(f);
        let v: Vec<i32> = serde_json::from_reader(rdr).unwrap();
        println!("reading data from reader");
        print_mem_stat();
    }

    // read to a string before parsing
    {
        let f = std::fs::OpenOptions::new().read(true).open(&path).unwrap();
        let mut rdr = BufReader::new(f);
        let mut content = String::new();
        rdr.read_to_string(&mut content).unwrap();
        let v: Vec<i32> = serde_json::from_str(&content).unwrap();
        println!("reading data as from string");
        print_mem_stat();
    }

    std::fs::remove_file(path).unwrap();
}

Output
start
This program currently uses 0.0010881424 MB of RAM.
The max amount that was used 0.0000010626391

writing data
This program currently uses 256.00116 MB of RAM.
The max amount that was used 0.25000876

reading data from reader
This program currently uses 256.00116 MB of RAM.
The max amount that was used 0.37500876

reading data as from string
This program currently uses 1013.4126 MB of RAM.
The max amount that was used 1.1146607


Memory usage may not return to exactly where it was before when you free values. The stats displayed by your example program are misleading. If you print_mem_stat between the tests I suspect you'll still see some usage higher than the floor. While your conclusion is likely correct. the way you're attempting to prove it here is faulty.

This doesn't seem like it even attempts to answer the question.
